# MVC Submit ID as Parent_ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've generated a partial view in VS and I'm trying to add a child item to certain parent on command. The question is how can I forbid to change Parent_ID and put an ID of an element that's comming from controller to partial view.
Simply, to do so, that I don't have to write parent_id in the field to submit it back to controller, I'd just need a new of a new element and show it's parent id in partial view. Hope it's not very confusing.
Thanks in advance.

Controller:

```
//MODAL POPUP FOR CREATE

        public ActionResult CreateNewItem(int? parent)
        {
            H_Table item = db_connection.H_Table.Find(parent);

            return PartialView(item);
        }

        //POST: CREATE ITEM

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateNewItem(H_Table item)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db_connection.H_Table.Add(item);
                db_connection.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(item);
        }
```

JS:

```
$('.add_btn').on('click', function () {
            $.get("/List/CreateNewItem", { parent: $(this).data('parent') }, function (data) {
                $('#modal_window').replaceWith('<div id="modal_window">' + data + '</div>');
                $('#modal_window').show();
            });
        });
```

Partial View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>H_Table</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PARENT_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PARENT_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PARENT_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
}
```